# Is there any solution to "Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit"

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I have google around and found that this was a problem earlier in PHP/Apache/MySQL, like in PHP v5.2.4. But I have that problem now, is there any thing I have done wrong? or is there any one that can help me solve this?

The log file prints, multiple times:

```
Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit
```

My system:

```
uname -a = 3.5.0-42-generic #65-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 23:38:22 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

php -v   = PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2013 19:36:09)
           Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
           Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

mysql -V = Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

apache2ctl status =  Server Version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.8.4 mod_fastcgi/
                         mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/
                         1.0.1c
                     Server Built: Jul 12 2013 13:37:01
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error one time , check this solution :

[fix-error-my_thread_global_end-1](http://forums.eukhost.com/f15/fix-error-my_thread_global_end-1-threads-didnt-exit-5612/#.Uo5rI8Qz1qU)

Comment: I've tried it, there is a bug fix for it in PHP 5.2.4. The solution worked back in 2006/2007. I've also tried to use new binaries for Ubuntu/Linux. 
My problem is that it is on a production server so I'm not alowed to compile anything on it, so is there any way to find binarys out there? or Do I need to compile up all the stuff (Apache, MySql, PHP) to fix it?